# Visual Studio : short cut Key : Duplicate Line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut for ***Duplicate Line*** command in **Visual Studio** 2008?

Some similar examples:

- in ***[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)***, I can duplicate the current line with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- in ***[EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com/)***: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- in ***[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)***: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>
- in ***[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)***, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>
- in ***[Vi/Vim](http://www.vim.org/)***, <kbd>yy</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
- etc.

Comment: Just for info, one of the many benefits offered by ReSharper is the ability to do this.

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/830a6482-3b8f-41a8-97b5-b9c581e5ad8b  Download this and alt + D will duplicate your selection or if nothing is highlighted it will duplicate the entire line.  Unfortunately visual basic macros don't seem to work in 2013, only js macros.

Comment: OMG, what is the problem to assign combination a person like for duplicating line??? I used to Eclipse. And Ctrl + D is for removing line. Why it's so complicated in VS???

Comment: @mghhgm below is the answer you're looking for.(shift+alt+down or shift+alt+up)

Comment: The vim example is not duplicating, it's ctrl+c;ctrl+v. "Yank" cuts, and p pastes. It's not quite the same as the other examples.

Comment: This has now become a default command in Visual Studio 2017, bound to Ctrl-E, V, but you can bind it to anything. Can duplicate line (if nothing selected) or duplicate selection, see: https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-now-you-can-duplicate-line-of-code-without-loosing-your-clipboard-content-within-visual-studio/

Answer (score 548, accepted):

#### In Visual Studio 2022

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>

#### In Visual Studio 2019

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

#### In Visual Studio 2017 (v15.6 and after)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

#### In Visual Studio 2017 (pre v15.6)

(edit) This feature is now built-in in VS2017: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> duplicates a line if nothing is selected, or duplicates selection. You can assign it to a different key combination, or find it in the menu:

[image: Duplicate line in VS2017]

See [this reference](https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-now-you-can-duplicate-line-of-code-without-loosing-your-clipboard-content-within-visual-studio/) for more information.

#### Pre VS2017, built-in method using clipboard

As @cand mentioned, you can just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will copy the line if nothing is selected.

#### Macro solution (pre VS2017)

If you'd like to implement a more complete solution, perhaps to create a simpler keyboard shortcut or you don't want to effect the clipboard, see this guide:

> Visual Basic:
>
> ```vb
> Imports System
> Imports EnvDTE
> Imports EnvDTE80
> Imports System.Diagnostics
>  
> Public Module DuplicateLastLineModule
>     Sub DuplicateLine()
>         Dim line As String
>         DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(0)
>         DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)
>         line = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text
>         DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
>         DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
>         DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(0)
>         DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = line
>     End Sub
> End Module
> ```
>
> To create the macro, just go to the macro explorer
> ("Tools->Macros->Macro Explorer" or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) and copy paste the code in
> a new module. Now just assign a keyboard shortcut to it:
>
> 1. go to Tools->Options...
> 2. under Environment, click Keyboard
> 3. in the "Show Commands Containing" textbox, enter "duplicate" (this according to the name you gave the module.)
> 4. you should now see the macro in the list below
> 5. choose "Text Editor" from the "Use new shortcut in" list
> 6. set focus in the "Press shortcut keys" textbox and hit the combination on the keyboard you wish to use for it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in
>    my case)
> 7. hit the "Assign" button
> 8. you should now see the shortcut in the "Shortcuts for selected command" textbox
> 9. hit the OK button
>
> And that's it. Enjoy!

Comment: I just tried it, and it's interesting that it repeats some extra characters when there is a "server-side code block" with short tags, like this: `<div>Profile.UserName: <%=Profile.UserName %></div>` - after duplicating this line using this macro, it becomes the following: `<div>Profile.UserName: <%=Profile.UserName %></div> %></div>`. As you can see, the last part is "repeated". When there are no server side code blocks in it, it works OK. Do you know a workaround for that? By the way, another interesting thing I experienced is that this macro is relatively "slow", which I didn't expect... :)

Comment: After Feb 2014 macros are disabled for security reasons. Scroll down and see MasterHD's answer for the workaround to get Wael's method to keep working even after the security update.

Comment: please update this answer to include http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/830a6482-3b8f-41a8-97b5-b9c581e5ad8b

Comment: Security reasons...   [UNPRINTABLE]  Anyway Ben's answer below works fine without screwing around in the registry.

Comment: i find Ctrl C + Ctrl V to be limiting in cases where i have already copied something onto the clipboard, and would like to duplicate a line before i paste.

Comment: `Ctrl + C` will copy the line if nothing is selected. AWESOME!

Comment: Why on earth is it *so hard* to implement a duplicate action or keybinding which most of the other editors do very efficiently and intuitively. :/

Comment: why its needed. I copied smth in other tab, i come to specific line in this tab, i duplicate line and then use <code> CTRL + V </code> to paste some code in. Otherwise i have to go and recopy other code part again...

Comment: Macros only seem to be in js

Comment: Guys, better answer is below from Vazgen Torosyan, scroll down.

Comment: In VS 2022 it seems to be Ctrl + shift + D

Comment: Ctrl+D is not the default in VS2019 on any of the PCs I have installed it on. I successfully use ewwink's solution below (Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard / Edit.Duplicate).

Comment: In VS 2022, `Ctrl` + `E`, `Ctrl` + `V`, duplicate on a new line, where as the posted solution `Ctrl` + `E`, `V` does not.

Comment: VS2019 v16.11.4 does not work ```Ctrl + D```. The correct is ```Ctrl + E, V```

Comment: it worked for me in Vs2019  v 16.0.3  by Ctrl + e,v

Comment: Ctrl + D also work with 2022 :) 
But the best is: set what you want in Options/Environment/Keyboard

Answer (score 145):

There's a free extension you can download [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/830a6482-3b8f-41a8-97b5-b9c581e5ad8b) that lets you duplicate lines without replacing the clipboard contents.

By default its bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, but you can change it to anything you want by going to Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard.  Type "Duplicate" in the search box and look for "Edit.DuplicateSelection" and edit the shortcut to whatever you want.  I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to be consistent with other editors.

Comment: This is the real answer you're looking for, everything else posted here is clever, but just not what was asked for.

Comment: `Edit.DuplicateSelection` does not appear to be present in VSE 2013.  Or anything else with the term _duplicate_ in fact.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/830a6482-3b8f-41a8-97b5-b9c581e5ad8b works for vse2013

Comment: Matthew, you have to click the HERE link and install the extension.  THEN you have to close visual studio and reopen it.  THEN you have to go to Tools ==> Options ==> Environment ==> Keyboard and THEN you have to type Duplicate and you will see it.  Then you can press F4 so it acts like QEDIT or whatever you want and life will be good.

Comment: Even if it's a bit painful to have to install another tool, this one does the job and does it well. Thanks !

Comment: How do you stop CTRL + D from duplicating a line on the existing same line ? It doesn't put it on a new line for me ?

Comment: To me, it is super weird that it is a part of VS Code and not part of Visual Studio... Probably cuz they don't want to mess it up for people who have been VS for years but c'mon...

Comment: @dvdmn the extension isn‘t needed anymore with VS17 because Microsoft finally included it. Command name is `Edit.Duplicate` and default shortcut is Ctrl+E, Ctrl+V

Comment: On Linux, Alt + D opens the debug menu. Ctrl + D is "add next occurrence"

Answer (score 103):

It's simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> , check this 
[link](http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2009/11/11/ldquosmartrdquo-duplicate-line-in-visual-studio-out-of-the-box.aspx). As long as you don't select any text, this will duplicate the line the cursor is over when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: There are numerous occasions where you don't want to go through the clip board, for example if you want to duplicate a line and then replace some content in it with something you have in the clip board.

Comment: Sure, but the question asked for a shortcut, not for a general solution for text editing, so I think that for simple purposes it's enough (at least it was in my case).

Comment: thanks, but I was expecting something like Ctrl+j in Edit Plus or Crtl+D in Notepad++ ... is there any in VS2008 or in VS2010

Comment: I've only found this one. However it's not that bad - of course easier would be to use ctrl+D, but if You want to duplicate 1 line in 100 copies You can do it using ctrl+c (without need to select anything, just put command prompt over wanted line) + 100 times ctrl+v. It's only one set of keystrokes more than ctrl+d solution. It can be more problematic if You want to do more complex duplication.

Comment: @Mason240 That was my initial reaction as well to the quoted part in the accepted answer however the additional information 'As long as you don't select any text, this will duplicate the line the cursor is over...' makes this an ideal solution in my case.

Comment: I think this DOES do what he wants but it screws up the clipboard.  A better solution is the one Ben proposed.

Comment: One addendum to this is that you can use the visual studio clipboard ring afterwards to get to a previously copied item. Ctrl+Shift+V.

Comment: This just plain does not work "as long as no text is selected". Nope, it just copies nothing thus never changing whats in the clipboard and then pasting in whatever was there. Stupid this has 76 upvotes.

Comment: That's answering how to use the clipboard, not how to duplicate a line.
What if you want to duplicate a line without replacing clipboard content?

Comment: _If you don't want to override current content of the clipboard and still need to copy/paste_: just select the text, press control and drag and drop the text where you need it to be copied.

Answer (score 87):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> works for me on VS2012 with no extension.

Comment: Works on VS2008 also!

Comment: Works in VS2017.

Comment: Need a solution without clipboard overwriting

Comment: Just for complement the answer, you only need to press the full combination for the first duplication. From the second one, just press Ctrl + V repeteadly as many as you need to keep replicating the line.

Comment: worked for VS2022 as well

Comment: It worked on V.1.78.2

Answer (score 34):

In Visual Studio 2013 you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Glad I strolled down.  This is what I wanted.

Comment: Working on VS Code Linux, too.

Comment: Need a solution without overwriting the clipboard

Comment: would be great if didn't override the clipboard

Answer (score 33):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> works for me in VS2012 with Resharper. It's Resharper's hot key.

Comment: no its not, only realised that after posting, but it is a Resharper shortcut. and if one has resharper installed, then this could help.

Comment: I have resharper, and didn't know that shortcut!  Thanks.

Comment: This is the default shortcut if you are using Resharper's "Resharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA" keyboard scheme. Resharper has you select the keyboard mapping during the install.  "Visual Studio" keyboard scheme is one of the choices. If you pick "Visual Studio" keyboard scheme, then Ctrl+D will be mapped to something else.

Comment: That's an answer to a ReSharper question.

Comment: Note that this also works when multiple lines are selected, i.e. you can duplicate a whole bunch of code, not just one line. Downside of course being that resharper isn't free (but it seems the .Net world is used to that more than the Java world I come from).

Answer (score 23):

Here's a macro based on the one in the link posted by Wael, but improved in the following areas:

- slightly shorter
- slightly faster
- comments :)
- behaves for lines starting with "///"
- can be undone with a single undo

```vbs
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80

Public Module Module1

    Sub DuplicateLine()
        Dim sel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        sel.StartOfLine(0) '' move to start
        sel.EndOfLine(True) '' select to end
        Dim line As String = sel.Text
        sel.EndOfLine(False) '' move to end
        sel.Insert(ControlChars.NewLine + line, vsInsertFlags.vsInsertFlagsCollapseToEnd)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Yeah this one actually works, the one in the accepted answer was copying random stuff into the new line. Nice work, thanks!

Comment: I did not find the Macros option in VS 2010 Express, can this be implemented there?

Comment: After Feb 2014 macros are disabled for security reasons. Scroll down and see MasterHD's answer for the workaround to get Mark's method to keep working even after the security update.

Answer (score 15):

In Visual studio 2017 and maybe other version **No need Macro or Extension**,

1. Go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboards`
2. Under `Show commands containing:` write `Edit.Duplicate`
3. Place cursor to `Press shortcut keys:` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and click `Assign` button
4. click `OK` to save your new keyboard shortcut

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me but in a different way.  I have VS 2022 and I had Resharper trial installed and it expired. After I uninstalled it, all my macros were wrong or non-existent. Every field was gray from this step-by-step after I selected Edit.Duplicate from that list. I had to press the Reset button and after that, change it directly from the "Shortcuts for selected command" field.

Answer (score 11):

If you like eclipse style line (or block) duplicating using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd>, below I post macros for this purpose:

```vbs
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module DuplicateLineModule
    Sub DuplicateLineDown()
        Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim lineNumber As Integer
        Dim line As String

        If selection.IsEmpty Then
            selection.StartOfLine(0)
            selection.EndOfLine(True)
        Else
            Dim top As Integer = selection.TopLine
            Dim bottom As Integer = selection.BottomLine

            selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(top, 0)
            selection.StartOfLine(0)

            selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(bottom, 0, True)
            selection.EndOfLine(True)
        End If

        lineNumber = selection.TopLine
        line = selection.Text

        selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(selection.BottomLine, 0)
        selection.EndOfLine()
        selection.Insert(vbNewLine & line)
    End Sub
    Sub DuplicateLineUp()
        Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim lineNumber As Integer
        Dim line As String

        If selection.IsEmpty Then
            selection.StartOfLine(0)
            selection.EndOfLine(True)
        Else
            Dim top As Integer = selection.TopLine
            Dim bottom As Integer = selection.BottomLine

            selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(top, 0)
            selection.StartOfLine(0)

            selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(bottom, 0, True)
            selection.EndOfLine(True)
        End If

        lineNumber = selection.BottomLine
        line = selection.Text

        selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(selection.BottomLine, 0)
        selection.Insert(vbNewLine & line)
        selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(lineNumber, 0)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 11):

In *visual studio code* (**WebMatrix**):

Copy Lines Down: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd>

Copy Lines Up: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>

Delete Lines: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

Comment: This is the best answer so far; it will even allow you to duplicate a full block of code -if so you desire- just by selecting multiple lines.

Tested in Visual Studio Code 1.7.2

Answer (score 10):

Why so many long drawn out methods to accomplish something so simple?  It takes less than a minute to download and install the extension from Microsoft.  The page says that it will bind it to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> by default, but for me it bound it to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> automatically in Visual Studio Community 2015 without any changes.

[Here's the link to download the extension from Microsoft.com.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/830a6482-3b8f-41a8-97b5-b9c581e5ad8b)

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio 2008, and not 2015 :)

Comment: It should be noted that this extension duplicates the selected lines, and not the selection. But it's still useful.

Comment: This one is most useful for me because I wanted a solution that did not replace what I had in the clipboard. This extension is exactly what I was looking for. And according to the extension author, this currently works for Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, and 2017.

Answer (score 8):

As I can't use Macros in my Visual Studio 2013 I found a Visual Studio Plugin (I use it in 2012 and 2013).
[Duplicate Selection](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/830a6482-3b8f-41a8-97b5-b9c581e5ad8b) duplicates selections and whole Lines - they only need to be partial selected. The standard shortcut is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

While I realize this is not a keyboard shortcut, I figured I would add this, as it does not require the usage of the clipboard and might help some people.

Highlight the row you want to duplicate.
Press control, mouse click the highlighted text, and drag to where you want to go to.  It will duplicate the highlighted text.

Comment: Achieves the same result with built-in functionality!  And the question only asked for a shortcut - not necessarily a keyboard shortcut!  Still, would be more awesome if the mouse didn't have to be involved.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this exists in Visual Studio 2008 but in Visual Studio 2010+ you can easily do this by:

Don't select anything, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> And then (without doing anything else) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

for **Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017** follow the link and download the extension

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctlajoie.DuplicateSelection
```

Now go into Tools > Options > Keyboard, and type "Duplicate" in the search box (the full command string is "Edit.DuplicateSelection"). Here you can bind it to any shortcut in the same way you would for any other command.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the macro that Wael posted: [**Duplicate line command for Visual Studio**](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/52), but it stopped working a week ago, I assumed because of a Windows update.
And I was correct, as of February 2014, Macros have been disabled in VS2010 (and 2008 apparently).

To fix this you'll either have to uninstall the security updates, or add one line of code into the config files as shown [**here**](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/).

On a 64-bit Windows machine default paths to these files are:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSA\9.0\VsaEnv\vsaenv10.exe.config`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

  ```
  ...
  <configuration>
      <runtime>
          <AllowDComReflection enabled="true"/>
          ...
  ```

  [image: editor screenshot]

You **MUST** run your text editor with **admin rights** or it won't work! Hopefully this helps anyone else who suddenly has their macro functionality pulled out from underneath them.

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio 2008 you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For those still viewing this question on Visual Studio post-2008, a real Edit.Duplicate has been added:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (VS 2017 15.6+)

Answer (score 3):

**For Visual Studio *Code* 2019**:

Edit menu keyboard shortcuts with: ***<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>*** and ***<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>***

Edit "Copy Line Down" (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd>) to your your own shortcut.

You can find it, with the command ID: *editor.action.copyLinesDownAction*

For me, It's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Just put your mouse on the line to copy and do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ,afterwards <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on the same line.
Works like magic :-)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is a new shortcut introduced in VS 2017 v15.6 that seems to do the exact thing that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>

> Ctrl + D will duplicate the line the cursor is in and insert it right below the line in focus. If you’d like to duplicate a specific set of code, simply select the portion of code you want to duplicate before invoking the duplicate code command.

It won't affect your clipboard

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/08/30/improving-your-productivity-in-the-visual-studio-editor)

Comment: Fresh install of VS2017 and VS2019: Ctrl+D is not by default mapped to Editor.DuplicateLine...

Answer (score 2):

if you have a macos version, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> can make the job for you

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

**My story:** started working in a new company, never used Visual Studio before. One of the first things - how to duplicate line. After setting up macro **ReSharper** told me: would you like to substitute my shortcut which was: "duplicate text" :)

Comment: resharper - very slow

Answer (score 1):

I use application link:[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) with below code saved in `CommentDuplikateSaveClipboard.ahk` file. You can edit/remove shortcuts it is easy.
 I have link to  this file `"Shortcut to CommentDuplikateSaveClipboard.ahk"` in `Autostart` in windows. 
This script protect your clipboard. 
If you are more curious you would add shortcuts to thisable/enable script. 
I sometimes use very impressive `Multi Clipboard` script to easy handle with many `clips` saved on disk and use with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd> to copy,paste,cut,next,previous,delete this,delete all.

```
;CommentDuplikateSaveClipboard.ahk

!c:: ; Alt+C === Duplicate Line
^d:: ; Ctrl+D
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Send, {END}{SHIFTDOWN}{HOME}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{END}{ENTER}{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{HOME}
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved =
return

!x:: ; Alt+X === Comment Duplicate Line
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Send, {END}{SHIFTDOWN}{HOME}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{LEFT}//{END}{ENTER}{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{HOME}
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved =
return

!z:: ; Alt+Z === Del uncomment  Line
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Send, {END}{SHIFTDOWN}{UP}{END}{SHIFTUP}{DEL}{HOME}{DEL}{DEL}
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved =
return

!d:: ; Alt+D === Delete line
Send, {END}{SHIFTDOWN}{UP}{END}{SHIFTUP}{DEL}
return

!s:: ; Alt+S === Swap lines
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Send, {END}{SHIFTDOWN}{UP}{END}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLDOWN}x{CTRLUP}{UP}{END}{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{HOME}
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved =
return

!a:: ; Alt+A === Comment this line, uncomment above
Send, {END}{HOME}//{UP}{HOME}{DEL}{DEL}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 you copy the entire line the cursor is on with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> to paste it.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2017 its `Ctrl` + `D` or `Ctrl` + `C` ; `Ctrl` + `V`
they both work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The command you want is **Edit.Duplicate**. It is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. This **will not** overwrite your clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

> On Linux Mint, you can do;

> ```
> **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 2** => *Duplicate up*
> ```

> ```
> **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 8** => *Duplicate down*
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a useful addition:
As a freebie, I just invented (well... ehm... adjusted the code posted by Lolo) a RemoveLineOrBlock macro. Enjoy!

```vbs
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RemoveLineOrBlock

    Sub RemoveLineOrBlock()
        Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim lineNumber As Integer
        Dim line As String

        If selection.IsEmpty Then
            selection.StartOfLine(0)
            selection.EndOfLine(True)
        Else
            Dim top As Integer = selection.TopLine
            Dim bottom As Integer = selection.BottomLine

            selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(top, 0)
            selection.StartOfLine(0)

            selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(bottom, 0, True)
            selection.EndOfLine(True)
        End If

        selection.LineDown(True)
        selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn,True)

        selection.Delete()

        selection.MoveToDisplayColumn(selection.BottomLine, 0)
        selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

in [VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) and also in [VS2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) you can select **Tools->Options->Keyboard** and you can choose in the scheme drop-down ***Resharper (Visual Studio)*** option, and you will get a mapping like if you were using [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), in this case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will do the trick for duplicating the line. Anyways, based on the [documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improving-your-productivity-in-the-visual-studio-editor/) this should be out of the gate in ***Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8*** or greater

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio Code : May 2020 (version 1.46)
Shift + UpArrow/DownArrow : To Duplicate the line of code

Comment: Question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: iMac : shift + option  + Down Arrow

Answer (score -4):

For visual studio 2010, try using these commands for quick line duplication (uses clipboard):

- Click on the line you want to copy.
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will copy that line.
- Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a blank below insertion point

  (Alternatively use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a blank line above the insertion point.)
- Then simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the line.

Comment: Very good step by step instructions for a copy and paste.  But the OP is looking for a method to duplicate a line...