# MSVC 2012 - Shortcut to duplicate line

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the key for duplicating a line in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?
(in Notepad++ it is ctrl+D )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio : short cut Key : Duplicate Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279000/visual-studio-short-cut-key-duplicate-line)

Answer (score 7):

Check this extension:

- Duplicate Selection extension : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/830a6482-3b8f-41a8-97b5-b9c581e5ad8b

Duplicate the line without touching the clipboard (as Notepad++ does).

Comment: Nice! You should be selected as the best answer dude!

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it absolutely clear

ctrl-C at the start of a line copies the whole line without your needing to select it

source [Shortcut for duplicating a line of code in Visual Studio 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894510/shortcut-for-duplicating-a-line-of-code-in-visual-studio-11)

Comment: Ctrl-C should copy the whole line from anywhere on the line.

Comment: Copying and pasting isn't the same as duplicating as ctrl+D in N++ preserves the contents of the clipboard.  In VS2010 I had a macro to do this but macros don't seem to be around anymore :-( If anyone knows a way to do it again in 2012 that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of [keyboard shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx), but don't see a duplicate on it. Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V may be your best bet or see if there's something you can define under Tools>Options>Keyboard.

Comment: thanq, 
no shortcut key for duplicate in visual studio